# IntelliJ console output with multiple (source.java:line) links on a line

Tags: intellij-idea

When my logging system outputs the source and line number in the proper format (name.java:linenumber), it appears in the output console like a link you can click on, taking you to the corresponding line number of that source code, which works great. Except my logging system prints like a stack trace, a series of source location on a single line, like this:

date/time - a logging statement - (Source1.java:123) (Source2.java:321) (Source5.java:11)

The thing is that IntelliJ only makes the first one a link. The remaining ones don't become clickable links.

Is there a way to configure IntelliJ to scan *all* source location for each line in the console output, and not just the first one for each line?

Comment: It's not possible to configure this behavior at the moment. Feature request is welcome at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: Aaaand... done.

Comment: 5 years later, RIP. I found a plugin (Awesome Console) that does this.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not available at the moment and the progress can be tracked at:

- [Highlight links with multiple (source.java:line) per line in the output console](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-197361)

Comment: Yep. I made that entry after, wait, that's you, suggested it to me.
It would be interesting not? I wonder why this is not a standard logging thing. Loggers reveal the source and line where the logging statement is made, but what about the rest of the call chain (or part of it)? To discover the source and line, you'd have to fetch the whole darn stack trace anyway, so might as well iterate through it and log some of it I would think. There are all kinds of other funky things possible to make logging better too, but that's another whole topic.

Answer (score 0):

Jetbrains never added it, but the plugin [Awesome Console](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7677-awesome-console) does.

> With this plugin all files and links in the console and terminal will be highlighted and can be clicked. Source code files will be opened in the IDE, other links with the default viewer/browser for this type.